# Pandas: Index of last non equal row

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame `F` with a sorted index `I`. I am interested in knowing about the last change in one of the columns, let's say `A`. In particular, I want to construct a series with the same index as `F`, namely `I`, whose value at `i` is `j` where `j` is the greatest index value less than `i` such that `F[A][j] != F[A][i]`. For example, consider the following frame:

```
  A
1 5
2 5
3 6
4 2
5 2
```

The desired series would be:

```
1 NaN
2 NaN
3   2
4   3
5   3
```

Is there a pandas/numpy idiomatic way to construct this series?

Comment: This is really confusing. What, for example, is "current row"?

Comment: huh??? The description is still very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['B'] = np.nan
last = np.nan
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        continue
    if df['A'].iloc[index] != df['A'].iloc[index - 1]:
        last = index
    df['B'].iloc[index] = last
```

This will create a new column with the results. I believe that changing the rows as you pass through them is not a good idea, after that you can simply replace a column and delete the other if you wish.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do this that avoid looping in python. Usually the pandas or numpy functions are much faster

Comment: I don't think it's significantly more efficient. Also, when you want to loop through it while holding the indexes, you might need to use the good old 'for'. I might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

[`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) or [`pd.Series.argmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argmax.html) on Boolean data can help you find the first (or in this case, last) `True` value. You still have to loop over the series in this solution, though.

```
# Initiate source data
F = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5,5,6,2,2]}, index=list('fobni'))

# Initiate resulting Series to NaN
result = pd.Series(np.nan, index=F.index)

for i in range(1, len(F)):
    value_at_i = F['A'].iloc[i]
    values_before_i = F['A'].iloc[:i]
    # Get differences as a Boolean Series
    # (keeping the original index)
    diffs = (values_before_i != value_at_i)
    if diffs.sum() == 0:
        continue
    # Reverse the Series of differences,
    # then find the index of the first True value
    j = diffs[::-1].argmax()
    result.iloc[i] = j
```